# Powershell invoke expression output inside static method

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do a automation script where I call different commands (executables, bats or cmdlets) depending on different conditions. These commands output several lines of logs plus progress.

I am trying to improve code reusability using classes. However I can't get the commands' output when calling these from inside a class method.

For instance, using this code:

```
Class SomeClass
{
    static [void] CallSomeExe()
    {
        & "Path\To\SomeExe.exe" args
    }
}

`& "Path\To\SomeExe.exe" args` # Shows command output in shell

`[Utils]::CallSomeExe()` # Doesn't show any output in shell
```

If I invoke the command in my main function directly ( `& "Path\To\SomeExe.exe" args` ) the output from the exe will be shown in the shell, but if I call the static method in the main function ( `[Utils]::CallSomeExe()` ) no output will be shown.

A solution to show the log would be capturing the invocation result ( `$out = & "Path\To\SomeExe.exe" args` ) and return it to the main function. However, as generally it is a slow process and displays progress info I would prefer to stream it rather than waiting for all the output when the invocation ends.

I'm confused because this works inside a function, but not inside a class.

Is there a way to make it display output when calling from the static method?

Answer (score 0):

Classes follow a more traditional structure when it comes to output.  You need to define the output type and explicitly return.

```
Class SomeClass
{
    static [string[]] CallSomeExe()
    {
        return & "Path\To\SomeExe.exe" args
    }
}
```

The `[void]` in your original script indicates it does not return output.

Comment: I believe that this is the solution that I proposed and said that would do it for my problem. Because if I call a command that compiles something and writes custom output, warning or errors, I want to see the output live. Waiting 5 or 10 minutes to see the full output in not a solution for my case.